# UIScrollView with UIButton doesn't scroll when touch down on button

Tags: iphone, uikit, scroll, uiscrollview, uibutton

I've got a `UIScrollView` in my `UIView`. I've added some `UIButtons` to the scroll view.

If I touch down not on a button and drag, the scroll view drags fine.
If I touch down on a button and drag then the scroll view doesn't move.

I want the scroll view to always scroll around if dragged and the buttons only get selected on the `Touch Up Inside` event.

I don't want to check *"Delay Content Touches"* because I don't want to have to wait for the delay.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Regards,
Rich

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no automatic way of doing that. You have to manually handle the touch event, and then determine what the user wants to do, if he moves the finger X pixels up or down, then he wants to scroll, and if he releases the touch inside the button, then he probably wants to activate that action.

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps just outdated, but Redent84's answer is plain wrong.

You can solve this by adding:

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```